# Does the law of a Feller process depend continuously on the initial condition?

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $E$ be a locally compact and separable metric space, and suppose $X$ is a Feller process with transition function $P_t$. To be precise, let $C_0$ denote the space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity, suppose $P_tf\in C_0$ whenever $f\in C_0$, and
$$\sup_{x\in E}|P_tf(x)- f(x)|\rightarrow 0$$
as $t\rightarrow 0$.

Let $P_x$ denote the law of the process started at $x\in E$. It is stated on page 625 [of this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aop/1298669175) that the laws $\{P_x\}_{x\in E}$ are continuous in the space of cadlag paths with the Skorohod topology, by this I mean that if $x_n\rightarrow x$ in $E$, then $P_{x_n}$ converges weakly to $P_x$ as measures on Skorohod space. A more general question is very briefly discussed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/104838), however I've been to unable to find a reference.

Do you know of a book or paper where this is proved?

Comment: While I find this question interesting (and I do not know the answer off the top of my head), if I am not mistaken, the authors only claim *weak* continuity of laws.

Comment: Yes you are right, I really mean continuous in the same sense as the authors, that is, if $x_n\rightarrow x$ in $E$, then $P_{x_n}\rightarrow P_x$ weakly as measures in Skorohod space. I've edited the question to make this clearer. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I just stumbled upon a paper where, as far as I understand, a reference for the result you ask is Theorem 4.2.5 in: Ethier, Kurtz, *Markov processes: characterization and convergence*, Wiley, 1986. I did not check this, though.